# strong enough to cause damage vs so strong that

Tags: comparative-constructions

> The earthquake is strong enough to cause damage only near its epicentre.

If I change this sentence into so  adjective that,

> The earthquake is so strong that it can cause damage only near its epicentre.

I think it is grammatically correct but it is a bit strange due to the word "so" and "only". Advise me how to correct it.

Comment: Is the first "near" in your second example meant to be "damage"?

Comment: The word "near" is repeated twice in in your second sentence: "*...is so strong that* ***it can cause near*** *only* ***near*** *its epicentre*" It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

> The earthquake is so strong that it can cause [damage] only near its epicentre.

I don't think this conveys the meaning you want.

It implies that if the earthquake were stronger, the extent of damage would be less. Or that if the earthquake was weaker, the damage would extend further from the epicenter.

> The earthquake is strong enough to cause damage only near its epicentre.

This version if parsed carefully might have the same implication, but most native English speakers would actually read it as being equivalent to a slightly different phrasing which I think is more clear:

> The earthquake is only strong enough to cause damage near its epicentre.

This version makes clear that we want to say the earthquake is not very strong, and because of that, the damage was not too great.

Answer (score 1):

*Only* is misplaced in your "input" sentence:

> The earthquake is strong enough to cause damage only near its epicentre.<sup>†</sup>

This implies that an earthquake must equal ***or exceed*** some level of strength "to cause damage only near its epicenter"—which would mean that only a ***weaker*** earthquake would cause damage farther away!

That of course is absurd, and compels the reader to pause and reparse. What is meant is

> The earthquake is only strong enough to cause damage near its epicentre.

And by the same token your rewrite would be

> The earthquake is only so strong that it can cause damage near its epicentre.

But that is a very awkward and unidiomatic way of expressing that thought. Stick with *only .. enough*.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>A century ago this might have been phrased *The earthquake is strong enough **only** to cause damage...*, but this is rarely encountered today.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could recast your sentence like this:

> The earthquake is **not strong enough** to cause damage **beyond** its
>   epicentre.

or

> The earthquake is **only strong enough** to cause damage **at** its epicentre.